# Is it possible to have one Discord bot DM another bot?

Tags: node.js, testing, chatbot, discord, discord.js

I'm building out an `automated test bot` that is meant to test the commands of my `main bot`. Everything is working fine except that my `test bot` doesn't seem to be able to receive DMs from the `main bot`.

I'm currently using discord.js

```
message.author.send('test dm from one bot to another')
```

and getting the error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
```

Is there a setting for the bot, or a possible workaround so that I can test my bot's DM functionality?

Both bots can receive DMs from users just fine.

Comment: You apparently can't send messages to bots with another bot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, I don't think it is possible for a bot to send a DM to another bot.